# Excel Grouping and Logic

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have some data in Excel. This is already sorted into the correct order. I require to set the value in a new column to true if it is either a solo record (ie only one distinct ID#) or if there are several entries for that same ID# then set the last one listed to True and the other ones above for that ID# to False. For example:

```
ID#   New Column    
001   True    
002   True    
003   False    
003   True    
004   False       
004   False    
004   True    
005   True
```

I need to be able to apply a cell formula to the Excel sheet to auto generate this new column or to run a macro to populate the column. Any help appreciated as this is beyond my skills with Excel!

Answer (score 1):

Write the following formula into B2

```
=(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)-COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2))=0
```

which is the short version of

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)-COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2) = 0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

and copy it down.

For data sorted by `ID#` the following formula would be faster:

```
=IF(A2=A3,FALSE,TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi this works without the =0 part at the end can you let me know what that is doing?

Comment: @83dons actually it should work with the `=0`. Without it returns only numbers. But with `=0` it sould return `True` or `False`. See my edit and test if the long version works for you.

Comment: I found out that the following is better as it is less drain on resources than the above: =IF(A2=A3,"False","True")

Comment: Well if data is sorted, of course this is shorter. I was thinking about unsorted data. But you should use `=IF(A2=A3,FALSE,TRUE)` if you want to return a boolean type.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes we have to pre-sort the data.